# Why are tags now limited to 24 characters?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

> **This question is now a duplicate of:**
>
> [Increase tag length to 30 characters](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/increase-tag-length-to-30-characters) on meta.gaming.stackexchange.com

When we at Gaming complained about the tag limit being too short, we were told that the current limit of 25 characters was set in stone and would never change. Since game name is pretty much the only form of tagging going on the site, this was already pretty painful.

You don't have to go exotic and pull games like "[Do-Don-Pachi Dai-Fukkatsu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-Don-Pachi_Dai-Fukkatsu)" or ["むかしむかしあるところにとてつもなく仲の悪いツインテールの姉妹姫様がいらっしゃいましたとさ](http://www.forest.impress.co.jp/article/2007/11/29/twintail.html)"; even more common games like "[Need for Speed: Most Wanted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Need_For_Speed_Most_Wanted)" or "[Spider-man: Shattered Dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiderman_Shattered_Dimensions)" just do not fit in 25 characters.

Today, I find the limit changed. Downwards. **The tag length limit is now 24 on at least Gaming and Ubuntu** (v 2010.9.14.4) and I assume it has changed on other SE sites as well. MSO is still at 25 characters (v 2010.9.14.1).

- Why has this happened? Is the change by design?
- How do you suggest we tag questions about topics that just do not fit in the allotted space?

Comment: Suggestion: Use hash values for all game titles!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/tagging-suggestions), it has actually been 24 characters since the private beta, and I would hazard to guess it was actually the same when Web Apps started a week earlier. I did testing around that time to confirm it is limitted to 24 and not 25 on the SE 2.0 sites. So it's more of a question of "Why is it limitted on SE 2.0" more than "Why now", I suppose.

Comment: Fair enough. Going to open a feature-request about it then.

Comment: @badp Please do. While I haven't seen any 25 char cases (but *way* too many 26 char cases, which I have been rather vocal about), knowing why we even lose just one character would be nice.

Comment: [done](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/increase-tag-length-to-30-characters) (on meta.gaming)

Comment: obviously Jeff uncerimoniously gave it a downvote and a status-declined. I wasn't expecting anything else, to be completely honest.